# String Skipping characters in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have this string:

```
my $string = "Stuff1, stuff2, stuff3, stuff4";
```

I want to save the substring "stuff3" in another string. For an example, to save stuff1 I use the following:

```
$substring = substr($string, 0, index($string, ','));
```

Basically, this takes all the characters until there is a `','` char and that way, I have stuff1 saved in a different string. How can I save string 3?

Thank you,

Comment: `$third = (split(/, */, $string))[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could creep through it with `index`, but you're much better off [splitting](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the whole thing into an array.

```
my @words = split /\s*,\s*/, "Stuff1, stuff2, stuff3, stuff4";
print $words[2];
```